# Problems with scrapy - no items crawled

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap all the information from this website ("https://www.karl.com/experience/en/?yoox_storelocator_action=true&action=yoox_storelocator_get_all_stores") 
but I can't manage to write it in a file. My file is not even created. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy # Scraper
import json # JSON manipulation
import jsonpickle # Object serializer


class Karl(scrapy.Spider):

    # Needed var
    name = 'Karl' # Spider's name
    url = "https://www.karl.com/experience/en/?yoox_storelocator_action=true&action=yoox_storelocator_get_all_stores"

    start_url = [
        url,
    ]

    # Called from Scrapy itself
    def parse(self, response):
        filename = '%s.json' % self.name
        response = json.loads(response.body)
        response = jsonpickle.encode(response)

        with open(filename, 'w') as f: # Save the JSON file created
            f.write(response)
```

When I run scrapy crawl Karl, these are the last lines that I get:

```
2018-07-24 16:02:25 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-07-24 16:02:26 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 
pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-07-24 16:02:26 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-07-24 16:02:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-07-24 16:02:26 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 24, 14, 2, 26, 861204),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 54804480,
 'memusage/startup': 54804480,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 24, 14, 2, 26, 550318)}
```

Can you guys help me ? I'm working with scrapy for quite a while now and it's the first time this is happening. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your spider: `start_url` should be `start_urls`, plus you need a variable `allowed_domains`. Also there is no need to declare `url` additionally.

Your code should be:

```
class Karl(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'Karl'
    start_urls = ["https://www.karl.com/experience/en/?yoox_storelocator_action=true&action=yoox_storelocator_get_all_stores"]
    allowed_domains = "karl.com"

## Snip ##
```

You can also use `scrapy genspider` to generate a new spider which will use the default template and can be helpful in such cases.